# Why does $(x+3)/(x-4) \geq 0$ not include 4 in the interval result?

Tags: inequality

Wolfram alpha, the book I am going through, an other sources all give the resulting interval for:
$$
\frac{x+3}{x-4} \geq 0
$$
as:
$$
    (-\infty, -3] \cup (4, \infty).
$$
I am struggling to understand why 4 is not included in the set, when applying 4 into the inequality results in a positive infinity, which is definitively greater than 0?

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: The expression is undefined at $x=4$.

Comment: is it undefined, or does it go to infinity, because positive infinity is certainly greater than 0!

Comment: $\pm\infty$ is not a real number.

Comment: do you mean that when you put for $x$ numbers close to $4$ but bigger than $4$ you get $\frac{x+3}{x+4}$ is large positive?

Comment: "when applying 4 into the inequality results in a positive infinity" Nope, it does not "result" in this.

Comment: @Did - Can you explain your comment, why does (n>0)/0 not create infinity

Comment: Approaching $4$ from the left yields a large negative value, while approaching $4$ from the right yields a large positive value. Even if you allow infinite limits, this one can't be defined because of the ambiguous sign. If it had been $$\frac{x+3}{(x-4)^2}$$ then $+\infty$ would have been more acceptable.

Comment: First let me note that you use a precise language out of its domain of validity. Second, if I try to decipher what you have in mind, I arrive at the idea that you think we should count x=4 as a solution because the ratio would be +oo when x=4 and because +oo would be nonnegative. But one could equally say that the ratio is -oo, no? Conclusion: better play the math game with the rules of the math game (or, transgress its limits but only if one knows exactly what one is doing).

Comment: @Did - If you put your comment just above this one (Mine) where you explain the positive versus negative infinity, I will mark it as the answer I was looking for :-)

Comment: User @Arashium already explained this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How do you know

$$lim_{x \to 0}\frac1x$$

is $+\infty$ ?

if $x \to 0^-$

then it is $-\infty$

Beside that, $\frac10$ is undefined not $\infty$. Do not confuse it with limit. Any number more than 4 (even with tiny small value higher) matches your example which is fair enough.

Comment: This answers nicely shows why one cannot extend the defintion, and in fact does not get a *positive* infinity.

Comment: Actually, Im not sure I agree with you on this, if you put 1/0 directly into wolfram alpha, it indeed gives back an infinite result!  Thus, it actually does move towards infinity

Comment: @trumpetlicks for me `1/0` into W|A gives "complex infinity" as result. In other words an unsigned infinity. This is perfectly in line with this answer.

Comment: @trumpetlicks I checked that. The symbol is not normal infinity. Look at the ~ upon it. It means something very far in any direction. Not necessarily positive.

Comment: Just for clarification, so just because 0 becomes a result in the denominator, doesn't mean that we know per-say the sign of the zero itself, which is what makes it indeterminate?

Comment: @trumpetlicks Yes. Different definitions result in either "complex infinity" or "undefined". But everybody agrees that it has no clear sign.

Comment: @trumpetlicks In any case Wolfram Alpha does not get the final say on anything. In this case, $\frac{1}{0+\epsilon}$ is positive large, while $\frac{1}{0-\epsilon}$ is negative large. So $\frac10$ can't be interpreted as either $+\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Comment: @trumpetlicks Attention that universal set of wolfram alpha seems to be complex numbers not real numbers. see 
: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5Bx%5E3%3D%3D1%2Cx%5D

Comment: @trumpetlicks compex infinity not only can refer to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ but also $(+i \infty)$, $(-i \infty)$ or any combination of them such as $(-\infty +i \infty)$ or $(5 -i \infty)$

Comment: @trumpetlicks if you're still confused I recommend plugging in 3.9, 3.99, 3.999, 3.9999 and so on into the expression until you're convinced it's never going to be positive until you plug in a number bigger than 4.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that $4$ is not in the domain of the function on the left or you inequality. You can't evaluate that expression at $4$ because you would be dividing by $0$.

Remember that when you are asked to solve
$$
\frac{x+3}{x-4} \geq 0
$$
you are asked for the set of all *real numbers* $x$ such that when you compute $(3+x)/(x-4)$ then you get a non-negative number. And you simply can't evaluate (or apply as you say) the expression at $4$.

Answer (score 0):

The implied domain for:

$$\dfrac {x + 3}{x - 4} \ge 0$$

is a subset of all real numbers $x$ that satisfy the inequality. Whatever convention you define for $\dfrac 7 0$, if you feel you need to create some sort of definition, will yield results inconsistent with the properties of real numbers.

The fact that some computer algebra system returns *unsigned* infinity for $\dfrac 7 0$ is merely a *convention* used in some complex analysis settings. Even in those settings, it doesn't behave like a number. With complex numbers, your inequality doesn't make sense anyway, because the complex numbers can't be ordered by $\ge$ in any useful way.

The other answers already address why you can't choose $+\infty$ or $-\infty$, whatever meaning you attach to those two symbols.

Answer (score 0):

By Inequality:
Here $4$ is free boundry number and by associated equation solution gives $x=-3$.
So we have three region (-∞,-3),(-3,4),(4,∞).
Region (-∞,-3) and (4,∞) are true. And Region (-3,4) is false. So solution set is $]-∞,-3]U]4,∞[$